# How to use map in linux kernel for key value store?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to implement key value store in linux kernel with hash table.
Can anybody point out a suitable example using maps ?

I will be getting the key from user space and I want to **read/write/update** the value in kernel space.
Are there any protection mechanism for the same like we have in for hash as hash_add_rcu?

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is a hash table *is a map*. The reason that there is no abstraction to a "map" type API in the kernel is because you are responsible for everything in the kernel. Not only that, the way hashmaps are implemented in the kernel allows a single record (value) to be a part of multiple maps, and interweave multiple indirections and create arbitrary relational records.

Security is another concern. In most cases, when you get any data from user-space you should treat it like garbage: In particular, you cannot trust the userspace to give you valid keys, and use them directly, say for a map lookup. You should have an opaque mechanism to check the validity of the key (e.g. size) before reading/writing/updating values.